# Asking feedback and contact data after leaving signup form

Tags: registration, privacy

Is it smart to do this ?.
Everybody clearly wants to know why the user that was willing to signup leaved the form.

The only thing that could backfire are the users that wanted to signup at later time and the form nagging them for feedback / contact data made them not do it.

Comment: Recording unsubmitted form data is a *huge* privacy breach.  I strongly advise against this.

Answer (score 1):

So, if someone cancels out of handing over their contact details and signing up to your site/app, you want them to then hand over their contact details in the form of feedback instead? Yeah, I don't think that's going to go down too well with users.

And in any case, if you do collect feedback how can you be sure it's accurate? If everyone ticks the feedback button of '*I don't have time to signup now*' how would you know that is *really* the reason they're cancelling? They might just be ticking the first box they see just to get away.

And in addition, what are you actually going to do with this feedback once you receive it? Is it just going to be looked at and someone in marketing says 'oh that's interesting' and nothing happens with it then it's pointless still.

There are plenty of analytics packages out there that can give you more accurate feedback without impacting the user (you can tell if people struggle with certain fields for example) or you can AB test different versions of signup forms to see if one is any better than the other. Those don't annoy users and will give you useful information. Some arbitrary form asking for email address (when the user has already decided they don't want to hand it over) and then some random checkboxes or text fields that you have no way of knowing if the entered information is true or not is just unnecessary and annoying. And don't forget that you've probably already annoyed the user in some way if they've decided to abandon signup. Don't annoy them further.

Comment: its a b2b and i wanted to do that only to users that returned to landing page after visiting signup form.  we are using analytics and our feedback/contact would be nothing different then that chat / feedback badges that open them self.   i know it might be annoying, that is why i asked the question.  I saw that only on one page in the wild.  How would it work if i did not show them modal but a customized message on landing page and one input filed. so that i am bugging them ?